# Different between if else and return

Tags: c#, boolean-expression

My first snippet:

```
public bool isSmall(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < Smallest)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

My second snippet:

```
public bool isSmall(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (x < Smallest)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

What I want is `if (x == 0)` to just return true, if not do another comparison, `if (x < Smallest)`, and if true return true, otherwise return false.
I know my fist and second code do the same thing, but I am wondering which way to write it is better, affection, and safe? do they have any real differences? Or is it just two ways to write it?

Comment: You can just write `return x==0 || x< Smallest`

Comment: Java and C# are two different languages

Comment: what do you not understand about if else and return..?

Comment: @FirstStep All paths provides a return.

Comment: There is literally no difference.  The choice is up to you.

Comment: Looking at the IL for both of those snippets seems to indicate that they are identical except for a couple of `nop` instructions.  (Using LinqPad to view IL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do the same thing. The second one could be slightly more efficient if the code was compiled directly as written (since there is one less branch statement because of the omitted else). However, all modern compilers will optimize this so that they are exactly the same.

To answer your question (which is better), whichever is easier for you to read and understand is better since they do the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler will probably optimize either one of your routines to the following:

```
public bool IsSmall(int x)
{
   return (x == 0 || x < Smallest);
}
```

To see why, write out & fill in a Boolean truth table for each set of methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what are you talking about, and I agree with you. However, I just want to know something deeply. Such as how does the compiler will treat my codes? Just like you said, the compiler probably optimizes my code, but which way is affection and save?

Comment: The only way to know is to look at the compiler's output and inspect it.  C# is compiled to a language called CIL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), which you can open up in any text editor and look at. Many, many engineer-hours have gone into whatever compiler you're using to recognize various code patterns and optimize them. By the way, if you're happy with the answer, please click the green check mark next to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Both is readable but in terms of different perspective.

First one is safer because more readable(readable in terms of you can read it and illustrate in your head easier)

I generally use second one, it looks cleaner(seems more readable but more complicate to be understood)

About readability; for small number of if-else the first one is better but many number of if-else (like 10) second one is better.